Jest with TypeScript - Import assertions are only supported when the '--module' option is set to 'esnext', 'nodenext', or 'preserve'
I'm trying to use Jest in my Express API with TypeScript. However, every time I try to execute npm run test, Jest complains about the ESM.
I've tried many configurations, but none of then solved the problem. Anyone knows how can I solve it?
I installed jest and ts-jest. My tests are in src/__tests__/. Here is my jest.config.js (created using npx ts-jest config:init):
/** @type {import('ts-jest').JestConfigWithTsJest} **/
export default {
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    transform: {
        '^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$': ['ts-jest', {useESM: true}],
    },
    testMatch: ['**/**/*.test.ts'],
};

When I try to execute Jest, it throws:
Import assertions are only supported when the '--module' option is set to 'esnext', 'nodenext', or 'preserve'.

It happens because there is an assertion like this in app.ts, a file that is imported in a test:
import swaggerFile from '../swagger-output.json' assert { type: 'json' };


Having fought this battle recently myself, I can't give you a solution only a recommendation to try vitest instead. I never could get jest to work properly with esmodules and nor could my coworkers. We didn't want to fall back to commonjs so we just went with a framework that worked.
